# Calling a solidity payable function with etherjs

Tags: solidity

I have a basic Solidity smart contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract TestContract {
    uint256 public _blockTimestamp;


    function accumulated() public payable returns (uint256) {
        _blockTimestamp = block.timestamp;

        return 1;
    }
}
```

And using remix IDE I can compile it and check the value of `_blockTimestamp` changing after executing the `accumulated` function.

Now, I can deploy the contract and check the value of the public variable without any problem with etherjs:

```
  const provider = new providers.JsonRpcProvider(getEnv('RINKEBY_NODE_URL'));
  const wallet = new Wallet(getEnv('ROPSTEN_PRIVATE_KEY'), provider);

  const TestContract = TestContract__factory.connect(getEnv('TEST_CONTRACT'), provider);

  const _blockTimestamp = await NFTLTokenContract._blockTimestamp();
```

The problem is when I try to execute the function `accumulated`. Being a payable function I need a signer:

```
  const provider = new providers.JsonRpcProvider(getEnv('RINKEBY_NODE_URL'));
  const wallet = new Wallet(getEnv('ROPSTEN_PRIVATE_KEY'), provider);

  const TestContract = TestContract__factory.connect(getEnv('TEST_CONTRACT'), provider);

  const _blockTimestamp = await TestContract._blockTimestamp();

  const accumulated = await TestContract.accumulated('1', wallet);
```

But I still get the error:

> Error: sending a transaction requires a signer
> (operation="sendTransaction", code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION,
> version=contracts/5.5.0)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to call a non-view function by using only a provider, you must provide a signer in order to call the function.

Try connecting to the contract using the wallet as the signer:

```
const TestContract = TestContract__factory.connect(getEnv('TEST_CONTRACT'), wallet);
```

Comment: Hello, can you be more specific about what should I add/remove to the code?